# Facebook-style scroll down refresh using jquery

Tags: jquery

I am able to pulling the content(from database) on scroll up using jQuery `$(window).scrollTop()` in the following way,

```
var offset = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    /*scroll up*/
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == $(document).height() - $(window).height()){
        offset += 10;
        getList();
    }
}
});

//scroll down
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
        offset = 0;
        //again need to refresh the content from 0 to 10
        getList();
    }
});
```

If I scroll down, I need some kind of animation (i.e. space on the top and loader icon ) effect like Facebook).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used to do like this in my application and it works great :

```
$(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).scroll(function () {

         if ($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
              GetDoctors(); // reached bottom while scrolling so load results
            }
        });
    });
```

Here is the link to my [blogpost where i made a tutorial like thing of it after implementing](http://developmentpassion.blogspot.com/2013/12/infinite-scroll-paging-in-aspnet-mvc-4.html)